# How to check if commenter is the_author?

Tags: comments, author

What's the best way of checking if my commenter is also the author of the post that he post comment on?

I know there's a css way (`.byauthor`), but how about PHP? How to compare post author with comment author? I was trying with is_author(), the_author() and comment_author() but it just doesn't look right (what if somebody uses the same nickname as author?).

Here's my code for now:

```
<?php if(get_the_author() == get_comment_author()) _e( 'Author', 'theme' ) ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what you are meaning to do but, if you take a look at the `get_comment_class()` function that is responsible for generating the `.bypostauthor` class you can see how it determines if the commenter is the author

```
if ( $post = get_post($post_id) ) {
            if ( $comment->user_id === $post->post_author )
                $classes[] = 'bypostauthor';
        }
```

You should be able to use this to do something similar.