# Conditional/Check: IF comment author is the post author

Tags: author, comment-form

I'm trying to edit my comments.php so that I can conditionally display `//do something` if the comment author is also the post author. I have no idea what I'm doing but I've managed to throw this piece of garbage together as a start (what a joke)...

```
<?php if ( get_comment_author(global $wp_get_current_commenter();   wp_get_current_commenter() && $wp_get_current_commenter()->ID && == $post->post_author)) { ?>
// do something
<?php } ?>
```

I've read [this link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85847/how-to-check-if-commenter-is-the-author) but it's no more clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if ( $post = get_post($post_id) ) : ?>
<?php if ( $comment->user_id === $post->post_author ) :?>
//do something
<?php endif;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Also.

```
<?php 
global $post;
if( $comment->user_id === $post->post_author ) {
// do something
}
?>
```